# Segment fault iPhone executable

Tags: c, command-line-interface, segment

When I run my CLI program on my iphone i get a Segment fault: 11 error. I dunno what to do, I'm a noob at C.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
if (argc > 1 && (!strcmp(argv[1],"--help") || !strcmp(argv[1],"-h"))) {

    printf("#### redhai 1.2 ####\n");
    printf("-j Jailbreak\n");
    printf("-i Device info\n");
    printf("-a About\n");
    printf("*END OF HELP*\n");
    printf("####################\n");
    return 0;
}else if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-j")) {
    printf("Coding the jailbreak portion!\n");
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `argv[1]` without first checking if it exists. You need to first check if `argc > 1`.

```
} else if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1],"-j")) {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Huh. Gosh I am a slow typer. +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic. It is possible that you pass `NULL` to `strcmp` in case `argc` is less or equal to `1`. To fix it, re-order the checks like this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1],"--help") || !strcmp(argv[1],"-h")) {
            printf("#### redhai 1.2 ####\n");
            printf("-j Jailbreak\n");
            printf("-i Device info\n");
            printf("-a About\n");
            printf("*END OF HELP*\n");
            printf("####################\n");
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-j")) {
            printf("Coding the jailbreak portion!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```